# Running GNU parallel from input file while modifying colsep input

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I'm a novice with GNU parallel and I'm only semi-knowledgeable about bash in general so I would really appreciate some advice.

I want to read line by line through an input file containing a file path in the first column and the path to a second file in the second column, and for each line use the columns as input in a command. However, I need to replace part of the file name in column one to make my command work.

The file would look like this, two file paths separated by tabs:

```
path_to_file/filename1_combined_R1_001.bam \t path_to_file/filename1.fna
path_to_file/filename2_combined_R1_001.bam \t path_to_file/filename2.fna
```

What I would need to be able to do is remove the string "_R1_001.bam" from column one and replace it with my own string (e.g. _R1_fastq) to invoke a script called `removeM`. FYI, I'm not sure if I'm using `--colsep` correctly.The command is as follows:

```
parallel -j10 --colsep '\t' input_file.tsv removeM -1 {1}_R1.fastq -2 {1}_R2.fastq -i {2}  -f CoralRemoved_{1}_R1.fastq -r CoralRemoved_{}_R2.fastq`
```

As far as I can tell I could use basename removal (something like {1.} ) but I can't figure out how to remove more than just the extension (.bam).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this out for myself. I used --colsep to split the files into fields and then a regex to replace the string. The 1 before the equals signs say to print the first field while the regex within the equal signs do the string replacement.

`parallel -j10 --colsep '\t'-a $2 removeM -1 bamToFastq_{=1s/_R1_001.bam//=}_R1.fastq.gz -2 bamToFastq_{=1s/_R1_001.bam//=}_R2.fastq.gz -i {2} -f CoralRemoved_bamToFastq_{1}_R1.fastq -r CoralRemoved_bamToFastq_{1}_R2.fastq`

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding the exact command you want to run, but I think you can probably alter the file, with `sed`, as you feed it into **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
sed 's/_R1_001.bam/_R1_fastq/' input_file.tsv | parallel -j10 -colsep '\t' removeM ...
```

Note that this will not permanently alter your file `input_file.tsv`, instead, it modifies it *on-the-fly* as it passes it to **GNU Parallel**.

Note also that you can see what it is doing if you just run:

```
sed 's/_R1_001.bam/_R1_fastq/' input_file.tsv
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I appreciate your answer but it didn't get to exactly what I wanted. What you suggested would get me the desired format of the fastq files I wanted (first column) but then I would have to find a way to grab the associated file path in column two. I could maybe have done this by grep-ing the file within `back ticks` using the the first column as a search and piping to cut -f to get the second column but I didn't think that would function the same way in parallel. 

sed 's/_R1_001.bam//' input_file.tsv | parallel -j10 removeM -1 {}_R1_fastq -2 {}_R2_fastq  -i `grep {} | cut -f 2`

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the full question, so treat it as a comment.

Version 20170322 introduced dynamic replacement strings, which might be useful here.

A dynamic replacement string is a `--rpl` definition that takes an argument. The argument is grabbed with () in the replacement string and used in the code to run as $$1 (and $$2, $$3 ... if there are more ()-groups). Here are a few examples that each correspond to a Bash parameter expansion:

```
# Bash ${a:-myval}                                     
--rpl '{:-([^}]+?)} $_ ||= $$1',
# Bash ${a:2}                                                                      
--rpl '{:(\d+?)} substr($_,0,$$1) = ""',
# Bash ${a:2:3}                                                                    
--rpl '{:(\d+?):(\d+?)} $_ = substr($_,$$1,$$2);',
# Bash ${a#bc}                                                                     
--rpl '{#([^#][^}]*?)} s/^$$1//;',
# Bash ${a%def}                                                                    
--rpl '{%([^}]+?)} s/$$1$//;',
# Bash ${a/def/ghi} ${a/def/}                                                      
--rpl '{/([^}]+?)/([^}]*?)} s/$$1/$$2/;',
# Bash ${a^a}                                                                      
--rpl '{^([^}]+?)} s/^($$1)/uc($1)/e;',
# Bash ${a^^a}                                                                     
--rpl '{^^([^}]+?)} s/($$1)/uc($1)/eg;',
# Bash ${a,A}                                                                      
--rpl '{,([^}]+?)} s/^($$1)/lc($1)/e;',
# Bash ${a,,A}                                                                     
--rpl '{,,([^}]+?)} s/($$1)/lc($1)/eg;',
```

These are, by the way, enabled, if you use `--plus`.

So to remove a string (or more accurately: a regexp) from the end you can use:

```
$ parallel --plus echo {%_R1_001.bam} ::: MyOrganism_R1_001.bam
MyOrganism
```

Or to replace a string:

```
$ parallel --plus echo {/_R1_001.bam/_R1.fastq.gz} ::: MyOrganism_R1_001.bam
MyOrganism_R1.fastq.gz
```

Or you could make your own where you expressed how many .'s or _'s you wanted to remove:

```
$ parallel --rpl '{_(\d+)} s/([_.][^_.]*){$$1}$//' \
   echo {_1} {_2} {_3} ::: filename2_combined_R1_001.bam
filename2_combined_R1_001 filename2_combined_R1 filename2_combined
```

You could then have this `--rpl` definition in your `~/.parallel/config`.